# Asp.Net Core Custom Role Properties

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

Is it possible to add custom properties to the .Net Core EF Role class? I know for the `ApplicationUser` class you can add properties directly to the definition, but is there a way to do something similar with the `Role` class?

Something like

```
public class MyRole : IdentityRole
{
    public string CustomProperty { get; set; }
}

// What do I derive from here?
// Or do I/can I override the Roles property?
public ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<MyRole> Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You can derive from `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, MyRole, string>`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help!